# I want to make a custom shape like this

Tags: flutter

[image: This is a custom box]

I am trying to make a box like this. If I press on the "Product" button, then I need to show a box like this. But I cannot make it. I tried both clippath and custom paint. I can use visibility widget to show and hide – this is not problem. The problem is that I need to show a box like the picture I added here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `CustomPainter`. this is an example:

```
class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double progress;

  LinePainter({this.progress});

  Paint _paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeWidth = 4.0
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width * progress, size.height / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, _paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LinePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.progress != progress;
  }
}
```

for more information you can see [this page](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0).